# AWUS036NHA wireless adapter not shown in iwconfig or unable to be used with airmon-ng

Tags: networking, wireless, adapter

I have a AWUS036NHA wireless adapter with an atheros9271 chipset which is successfully installed in device manager and able to be used however when using iwconfig it shows no wireless extensions and in ifconfig it is shown as wifi1 instead of wlan which I’m unsure if that is a problem? When running airmon-ng start wifi1 it shows no interface chipset etc however I bought it from amazon and all comments etc say that it supports monitor mode, I’ve checked if I have to install it on linux which I have not done but If I try Sudo apt install firmware-atheros it says no package found- any help would be lifesaving?

Comment: Can you give us some more info? What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: latest version ofubuntu, also same issue on kali